# Hana: How to create a table type LIKE the type of another table?

Tags: sql, types, hana

I'm trying to create a table type which has a lot of fields, in SQLScript for a Hana machine.

I've tried some combinations of 'Like' and other keywords but it all comes out as a syntax error.

Furthermore, I could not find any hint of this in the SQLScript reference guide.

I've been creating tables LIKE [orignal table] with no data and inserting records into it - not practical :(

Thanks in advance.
Miguel

EDIT: to understand if the procedure 'get_object_definition' can be used with  tables with case-sensitive names.

In this image we can see the procedure calls, with the error message; in the image after, the tables and table types in each of the schemas.

EDITED: I got it, have to call the procedure with '  "  table_name  "  '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific command to create a type based on an existing table or another type.
What you can do is to get the definition of the table via

```
call get_object_definition ('<schema name>', '<table name>');
```

and edit the object creation statement to a CREATE TYPE statement. This is basically just changing the starting part of the statement and cutting away some parts at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lars. I was having issues calling the procedure for tables with case sensitive names... I don't think there is a solution for those...

Comment: Sure there is. Simply put the usual double-quotes in place:

e.g. call get_object_definition ('MY_SCHEMA', '"MyTable"');

Comment: Thanks for the comment Lars, I had tried that before - I might be doing something wronge here.... I've edited my question with some screenshots.